# Include PHP file into another file

Tags: php, html

I have one 'a.php' with form content. In 'index.php' file I have randomly generated uuid and given that id as a link, for eg, "0092f9f2-055a-4110-955a-ca581f0f9a8c.php".

When click on that uuid link, a.php file should be load without change the page URL.

Otherwise Please help me to load html content in that random link.

Comment: use include or require i guess

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I have static URL then I can include 'a.php' . But the URL is randomly generated so how do I include external php into randomly generated link from another php file?

Comment: What is the purpose of generating `0092f9f2-055a-4110-955a-ca581f0f9a8c.php` ? Why cant it remain as it is `a.php` ?

Comment: Hi, That is my work has to do.